# UITableView animation that starts quickly and slows down by the end

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation

I am programatically scrolling the table with animation. I want this scrolling to be same as the user scrolling (fast at beginning and slow at end). How to perform an animation that start with speed and then go slow in the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can basically use animation block with UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut of the scrollView / tableView.
curveEaseOut (From documentation):

> An ease-out curve causes the animation to begin quickly, and then slow
>   as it completes.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
        self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(0, 100), animated: false)
        }, completion: nil)
```

That way you control over the animation duration and manner.

Comment: can we control the speed.

Comment: Mmmm.. Maybe you do something creative by playing with nested animation blocks or multiple consecutive blocked with delays and also adding **[.beginFromCurrentState]** on following animation blocks so they perform smooth scrolling from current layer position.